# how to do select event in DevExpress XtraTree List

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, devexpress, xtratreelist

Hai,
  Am using DevExpress Tree List in C#.NET application .I want to know about how to trigger select event of  checkbox control in DevExpress XtraTree List.

example:

I'm using a treelist extra editors devexpress. The columns are loading from database and contain check boxes.when checked a check box and press an edit button i want to take the value as 1 for the corresponding checkbox.and want to save that value to database

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To learn how to obtain a cell value in the XtraTreeList, please refer to the topic available at:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument191

Does this help?